# Undefined inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch `Api` through `axios` call, using `useContext` embedded inside endpoint.
Before `axios call` the `userData` return value, but inside the `useEffect` it is undefined, and I have no idea why this is happening.

The part that will interest you guys since I have imported everything and so on

```
    /* Importing UseState, UseEffect */
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from "react";
/* Importing Axios */
import axios from "axios";
/* Styles Import */
import "./Badges.styles.scss";

/* Context Imports */
import {UserContext} from "../../../context/UserContext";


const Badges = () => {
 
  /* Axios call for badges starts */
    /* Creating the UseState for the badges */
    const {userData} = useContext(UserContext);
    console.log(userData);
    const [badges, setBadges] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    // /* Function to fetch the Api */
    //  /* Making the Axios call */
    useEffect(()  => {
      console.log(userData)
      axios.get(`/api/v1/user/gamification/${userData._id}`)
      .then(res => {
        setBadges(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },[])

  
   
   
  /* Axios call for badges ends */
    
  return ( .....
```

Comment: how many times the userData outside the useEffect prints ? Does it print only once ? .

Comment: Print twice in my console

Comment: Most likely, the hook with which you get `userData` does not have time to return the value you need before `useEffect` is triggered. If you need to execute a request every time `userData` changes, **just add it to the `useEffect` dependency array**, if only once, then in addition to the last step, **add a check if the request has already been started**

Comment: I added empty array under the catch if you mean that ?

Comment: Yes, try add `userData` to the array

Comment: It worked !! thanks

Comment: Okay, I will add to the answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(()  => {
   // assuming your userData is null initially
      if(userData) 
     {
      axios.get(`/api/v1/user/gamification/${userData._id}`)
      .then(res => {
        setBadges(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      } 
    },[userData])
```

Comment: Thanks Shyam, but If it worked userData inside the array ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the hook with which you get `userData` does not have time to return the value you need before `useEffect` is triggered. If you need to execute a request every time `userData` changes, **just add it to the `useEffect` dependency array**, if only once, then in addition to the last step, **add a check if the request has already been started**